# How do I use pulp and purescript development *without* an internet connection?

Tags: purescript

This morning I wanted to try a quick example, however, I noticed I couldn't do a "`pulp init`" without an internet connection.

Is there any way I could cache the pulp packages somehow so that creating a project doesn't fundamentally require an internet connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulp uses Bower for package management, so you can use Bower's facilities for offline work, including `--offline`, or pointing to local dependencies on disk.

Comment: Fantastic, I'll check this out!